# Foreign Key contraints are giving errors

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Im making a shop webiste and so im trying to make a table that has both my sell `table(Compra)` and my shirt `(camisolas) table`.

This is my sell(compra) table

```
    CREATE TABLE `compra` (
  `idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dataCompra` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `valorTotal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utilizador_idUser` int(11) NOT NULL
);
```

This is my shirts(camisolas) table

```
    CREATE TABLE `camisolas` (
  `idCam` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `preco` float NOT NULL,
  `camisola_imagem` varchar(150) NOT NULL
);
```

And this is the table im trying to make

```
    create table user_has_compra(
idCompra1 int primary key auto_increment,
idBuy int(11),
idCamisola int(11),
quantidade int(10)
);
```

```
ALTER TABLE `user_has_compra`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_compra_camisola` FOREIGN KEY (`idCamisola`) REFERENCES `camisolas` (`idCam`),
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_compra_compra` FOREIGN KEY (`idBuy`) REFERENCES `compra` (`idCompra`)
;
```

And this is the constraint´s im trying to make, thank you for the help.

The error I get is

> #1005 You cant create table loja.user_has_compra (error no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: Check this out for next time https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: @RiggsFolly i will thanks.

Comment: what's the exact error it gives you?

Comment: @FalcoGer   #1005 You cant create table `loja`.`user_has_compra` (error no. 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: since the answer doesn't work, double check the schema for those 2 tables.

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the parent columns of a foreign key need an index, so the lookups can be done efficiently.

In your schema, both parent tables are missing a primary key - so you cannot reference them in the child table.

I think you want:

```
CREATE TABLE `compra` (
  `idCompra` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,  --> primary key constraint
  `dataCompra` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `valorTotal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `utilizador_idUser` int(11) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE `camisolas` (
  `idCam` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,    --> primary key constraint
  `nome` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `preco` float NOT NULL,
  `camisola_imagem` varchar(150) NOT NULL
);
```

Then you can create the child table and add the constraints, using your existing code.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b293adb95ca313afe6fc2f824eebb920)**

Comment: I do have both of them as primary keys i did them like this    ALTER TABLE `compra`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`idCompra`,`utilizador_idUser`),
  ADD KEY `fk_compra_utilizador1` (`utilizador_idUser`);
And the other one is the same

Comment: In that case, your code should work, as shown in the DB Fiddle I just added to my answer.